# How can I make std::thread not struck the pragma?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads

I want to design a `timer` class, there is a function, which sleep some seconds, then call other function.

please see the code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func() { printf("timer thread function called\n"); }

class Timer {
 public:
  template <typename Fn> 
  void sleep_start(int sec, const Fn& f) {
    printf("sleep %d\n", sec);
    td_ = std::thread([sec, f]() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sec)); f(); }); 
    if (td_.joinable()) td_.join();
  }
  std::thread td_;
};

class A { 
 public:
  void start() {
    t_.sleep_start(10, func);
    printf("start function\n");
  }
  Timer t_; 
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.start();
}
```

this code can work well, but the `sleep_start` function stuck the program.

the real output is:

```
sleep 10
timer thread function called
start function
```

the ideal output is:

```
sleep 10
start function
timer thread function called
```

could you help on this? how to make the thread function not struck the program?

Comment: Do you know what `std::thread::join()` does, and how it works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually, I am confused about join, I know join is to wait another thread. but I can't understand. in my case, why put join in the deconstructor is correct. isn't it too late?

Comment: Yes, `join` waits for another thread to finish. So, you create a new execution thread, then wait for it to finish. So what, exactly, about your program's behavior was unclear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `td_.join()` early, `sleep_start` does not exit until thread finishes.

```
class Timer {
 public:
  template <typename Fn> 
  void sleep_start(int sec, const Fn& f) {
    printf("sleep %d\n", sec);
    td_ = std::thread([sec, f]() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sec)); f(); }); 
  }
  ~Timer() {
    if (td_.joinable()) td_.join();
  }
  std::thread td_;
};
```